# Upper bounds on art gallery problems using independent witnesses

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

Given a polygon $P$, the art gallery problem looks to find a smallest set of points that sees all of $P$. One way of bounding the number of guards necessary (from below) is to find a largest set of independent witness points, which are points whose visibility polygons are pairwise disjoint. Say the size of the smallest guarding set is $G(P)$ and the size of the largest witness set is $W(P)$. Then we have the trivial lower bound on $G(P)$, that $W(P) \leq G(P)$.

In arbitrary polygons, the size of the witness set does not help much with respect to an upper bound on the size of the guard set, i.e. there are examples with $\frac{G(P)}{W(P)} = \Omega(n)$.

Does the same hold for orthogonal polygons? It seems plausible to me that, unlike general polygons, a constant factor bound exists (maybe $\frac{G(P)}{W(P)} \leq 2$?), but my literature search came up empty. Can anyone point me at a reference, or a bad example?

Comment: I don't know much about this problem, but does the work of Steve Fisk apply in your setting? I believe he got very nice bounds for his version of this problem

Comment: @Michael: how is a guard set (guarding set) defined?

Comment: @Wlodzimierz: a *guard set* is a set of points such that every point in $P$ is connected to some point in the set by a segment that is nowhere exterior to $P$.

Comment: Thank you, @Joseph. Does it mean that $P$ is homeomorphic to a circle? Is the notion of "guarding" just--so to speak-- a little more general than of "seeing"? Are witnesses supposed to be inside the polygon (like visitors to a museum)? I guess it's time for me to check wikipedia or somethin' :-)

Comment: @Wlodzimierz: Yes, a simple polygon $P$ is homeomorphic to a disk. Yes, the guards are inside $P$ (or on its boundary). Yes, there is [a Wikipedia page on art gallery theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_theorem).

Comment: @DavidWhite: I am aware of Fisk's proof that $G(P) \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor$ (and the Kahn, Klawe, and Kleitman result showing $G(P) \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor$ for orthogonal polygons), but that is as a function of the number of vertices of the polygon, not the number of witnesses. Unless you're referring to something else?

Comment: @Joseph: thank you again for your kind answers. Now I'll click on the wiki-link you have provided.

Comment: "In arbitrary polygons, the size of the witness set does not help much with respect to an upper bound on the size of the guard set" - can you give an example?

Comment: Take a set of $n$ lines (no two parallel, no three intersecting at a point) and build a box containing all of the intersection points of the lines. Modify the box with a thin protruding spike at each intersection of the box with a line. Then the maximum witness set has size $1$, yet we need $n/2$ guards.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but it seems your example has many acute angles. In some papers, the authors relate to polygons with no acute angles (e.g. Graznya Zwozniak, 1998: http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~kowaluk/TOMEK/106-108.pdf ).  This is a compromise between general polygons and orthogonal polygons. (Not that it solves your problem, but maybe it adds some context)

Comment: BTW, interestingly, I happened to have a very similar question just now: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136448/cover-and-hide-with-squares/136462

Comment: I think Andras Frank has proved that if the polygon is half-convex in the sense that any two points on the same vertical line can see each other, then the min number of rectangles to cover the polygon equals the max number of points no two of which can be covered by one rectangle.
Unfortunately I cannot recall or find any relevant papers and, of course, I might be wrong...

Comment: @domotorp: This is proved in http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0602042.

Comment: @Ilya: OK, I asked Frank and here is the full story: The paper you linked to, by Chaiken et al., proves a weaker version, where the polygon has to be half-convex both vertically and horizontally. The fact that it is enough to demand one direction, was proved by Gyori: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589568490039X. Then later this was generalized by Frank-Jordan http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895685710441 and recently by Soto-Telha: http://math.mit.edu/~jsoto/localpapers/Soto-Telha-2dorgs.